# How to use each in Laravel as recurse?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

I have some objects like as:

```
array:8 [▼
  "_id" => MongoId {#261 ▶}
  "name" => "Objects"
  "default" => "900"
  "visibility" => "1"
  "type" => "2"
  "only_numbers" => null
  "value" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "59222778470e6c8e0b3c988a"
    1 => "59222880470e6cb90e3c9897"
  ]
  "available" => "1"
]
```

I try to display this on the page:

```
{{$field["name"]}} {{$field["value"]}}
```

But inside `value` exists keys on nested objects with the same structure.

So, I need to display these childrens.

How to do that using `each operator` in blade Laravel?

I tried:

@each('field.objects', $field["value"], 'nested')

Where template is:

```
<div class="fields-list row">
    {{dd($v)}}
    @foreach($field["value"] as $k => $v)
        <div class="col-md-4">{{$v['name']}}</div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            {{Form::checkbox('field_object['.\App\Helpers\Helper::getMongoIDString($v['_id']).']', $v["default"], array("class" => "form-control"))}}
        </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Comment: You can again loop through the `value` to get those values.

Comment: I updated question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only expect one level of recursion on the values, then it's a simple `@if` check:

```
@foreach($fields as $field)
    @if(is_array($field->value))
        @foreach($field->value as $key => $value)
            {{$value}} <br/>
        @endforeach
    @else
        {{$field->value}}
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Comment: @Blablacar That's fixed, Sorry about that.

Comment: In my case this is: ` @if(is_array($field['value']))
                                    @foreach($field['value'] as $key => $value)

                                    @endforeach
                                @else
                                    {{$field['name']}}
                                @endif
                                `  But what if nested object has nested `value` I mean in is_array loop?

Comment: It is not recursie